# How to create relation between new entity and existing entity without updating existing entity?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I have a Phone entity and a PhoneType entity. Each Phone has 1 PhoneType, and each PhoneType can have many phones.

I want to add a new Phone while using an existing PhoneType, but when I create the new Phone, how do I create the relation with an existing PhoneType without retrieving the PhoneType from the DB, and without updating the existing PhoneType?

I have tried simply creating a new PhoneType with the existing ID, which then attempts to update the PhoneType record. I do not want this update to occur.

I've also tried changing the CascadeType on the PhoneType field of Phone, but I have trouble understanding what these different types do.

In the Phone entity :

```java
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "phone_type_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private PhoneType phoneType;
```

And the PhoneType entity :

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Entity
@Table(name = "phone_type")
public class PhoneType {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "description", length = 175, nullable = false)
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "name", length = 175, nullable = false)
    private String name;
}
```

finally, creating the entities / relation :

```java
    return new Phone()
            .setNumber(phoneNumber)
            .setPhoneType(new PhoneType().setId(defaultPhoneTypeId))
  }
```

What happens in this case is just what you would expect, hibernate attempts to update the PhoneType with a bunch of null fields, where the PhoneType id = defaultPhoneTypeId.

Using CascadeType.MERGE, I get the following error :

```java
java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.hibernate.TransientPropertyValueException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing : com.phoneType -> com.PhoneType
```

While this is expected, I have no clue how to go about creating a relation with 1 new and 1 pre-existing entity.

Comment: You can either keep a reference to you existing `PhoneType` and reuse it or get `PhoneType` from DB by ID. Also you can read Vlad Mihalcea's post on [cascade types](https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-and-hibernate-cascade-types/).

Answer (score 0):

You have specified cascade type as `CascadeType.ALL`
This cascades all operation to the mapped entity.
So while saving phone you are cascading the save operation and asking the ORM to save the phone type as well.

Try removing it entirely. Default cascade type cascade no operation.

```
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "phone_type_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private PhoneType phoneType;
```

While creating a phone object, you can get the phoneType by Id from the DB and then set it in your phone object before saving.